# Issues with two overlapping divs

Tags: javascript, html, nav, overlapping

live site is here: http://www.mdw-art.com/new/index2.html
Image of my problem is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmygn.jpg

So the problem is when I hover over the navigation bars at the top, those are set to drop down on hover events.  However, when you mouse-down too far on the outer divs and hover over the previous/next navigation tabs the menu disappears.

In the image the menus are in the red, yellow, blue, and purple tabs, the navigation tabs are in orange, and the striped areas are where they overlap.

What is the best way I can correct this issue?  Am I setting it up incorrectly?  Can I drastically alter the z-index on hover events to prevent it from occurring?  Something else I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Can you please provide the javascript for making menu items visible?

Comment: JSFiddle of just the menu JS: http://jsfiddle.net/8DXRx/

Comment: When are you calling the menuOff()??

I checked  http://www.mdw-art.com/new/index2.html and jsFiddle given by you. I doubt you have an element in the page having id as "block".
And in jsFiddle there is a line thisBlock = document.getElementById(block);
Please check.